# problems with python Pandas converting int to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas read_csv to extract data and reformat it. For example, "10/28/2018" from the column "HBE date" will be reformatted to read "eHome 10/2018"

It mostly works except I am getting reformatted values like "ehome 1.0/2015.0"

```
eHomeHBEdata['HBE date'] = pd.to_datetime(eHomeHBEdata['Course Completed'])

#extract month and year values
eMonths=[]
eYears =[]
eHomeDates = eHomeHBEdata['HBE date']

for eDate in eHomeDates:
        eMonth = eDate.month
        eYear = eDate.year
        eMonths.append(eMonth)
        eYears.append(eYear)
```

At this point, if I print(type(eMonth)) it returns as 'int.' And if I print the eYears list, I get values like 2013, 2014, 2015 etc.

But then I assign  the lists to columns in the data frame . . .

```
eHomeHBEdata.insert(0,'workshop Month',eMonths)
eHomeHBEdata.insert(1,'workshop Year',eYears)
```

. . . after which print(ehomeHomeHBEdata['workshop Month']) returns values like 2013.0, 2014.0, 2015.0. That's type float, right?

When I try to use the following code I get the misformatted errors mentioned above

```
eHomeHBEdata['course session'] = "ehome " + eHomeHBEdata['workshop Month'].astype(str) + "/" + eHomeHBEdata['workshop Year'].astype(str)
eHomeHBEdata['start'] = eHomeHBEdata['workshop Month'].astype(str) + "/1/" + eHomeHBEdata['workshop Year'].astype(str) + " 12:00 PM"
```

Could someone explain what's going on here and help me fix it?

Comment: use this method to examine what is the data type of each column in your dataframe pandas.DataFrame.dtypes maybe 'workshop Month' is float and if you insert an int value it will cast it to float

Comment: 'workshop Month' is type series. The eMonths object it is created from is a list. The individual eMonth objects that go into the list are type int. Yet when 'workshop Month' is put into a df column it looks like a float.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To convert (*reformat*) your date columns as `MM/YYYY`, all you need to do is:

```py
df["Your_Column_Name"].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
```

> See **Section-A** and **Section-B** for two different use-cases.

### A. Example

I have created some dummy data for this illustration with a column called: `Date`. To reformat this column as `MM/YYYY` I am using `df.Dates.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')` which is equivalent to `df["Dates"].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')`.

```py
import pandas as pd

## Dummy Data
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020/07/01', end='2020/07/07', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Dates'])

# Solution
df['Reformatted_Dates'] = df.Dates.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
print(df)
## Output:
#        Dates Reformatted_Dates
# 0 2020-07-01           07/2020
# 1 2020-07-02           07/2020
# 2 2020-07-03           07/2020
# 3 2020-07-04           07/2020
# 4 2020-07-05           07/2020
# 5 2020-07-06           07/2020
# 6 2020-07-07           07/2020
```

### B. If your input data is in the following format

In this case, first you could convert the date using `.astype('datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]')` on the column. This lets you apply pandas datetime specific methods on the column. Try running `df.Dates.astype('datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]').dt.to_period(freq='M')` now.

```py
## Dummy Data
dates = [
    '10/2018', 
    '11/2018', 
    '8/2019', 
    '5/2020',
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Dates'])
print(df.Dates.dtype)
print(df)

## To convert the column to datetime and reformat
df['Dates'] = df.Dates.astype('datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]') #.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
print(df.Dates.dtype)
```

### C. Avoid using the `for loop`

Try this. You can use the inbuilt vectorization of pandas on a column, instead for looping over each row. I have used `.dt.month` and `.dt.year` on the column to get the month and year as `int`.

```py
eHomeHBEdata['HBE date'] = pd.to_datetime(eHomeHBEdata['Course Completed'])
eHomeDates = eHomeHBEdata['HBE date'] # this should be in datetime.datetime format

## This is what I changed
>>> eMonths = eHomeDates.dt.month
>>> eYears = eHomeDates.dt.year

eHomeHBEdata.insert(0,'workshop Month',eMonths)
eHomeHBEdata.insert(1,'workshop Year',eYears)
```

Comment: @NWWPA Does this solve the problem? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Your solution in part A is solves one of the problems but not all.

The eHomeHBEdata 'course session' value is fixed but the eHomeHBEdata['start'] still needs the month and date numeric values extracted by the for loop. e.g. and input date of '11/5/2020' will create an ouput value of '11/1/2020' for 'start.'

The reasons for that have to do with the CRM software into which I will load the output CSV.

Comment: @NWWPA Could you please share “input data” and “expected output data” as samples? Right now it is not clear to me what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: After the for loop above, the objects in the eMonths and eYears lists are type int. Somehow they are converted into type float after the assigning them to columns:

`eHomeHBEdata.insert(0,'workshop Month',eMonths)
eHomeHBEdata.insert(1,'workshop Year',eYears)`

I get "10.0" instead of "10" and "2020.0" instead of "2020"

Comment: @NWWPA Please check **Section-C** in my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have pasted together a work around by converting the type back to int from float but will experiment with your solution. I am a rank beginner when it comes to python and am appreciate the ability to approach problems from multiple angles.